# SSL on Load Balanced Nginx Server

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm experiencing some issues with my SSL setup on a client application.
The application is served from Nginx on an AWS EC2 instance.
I have an AWS load balancer in front of this server.
My SSL cert is installed on the Load Balancer and all traffic is routed to Nginx on the relevant port.

If I navigate to one of the webpages served by Nginx I get an SSL Certificate error in my browser.

If I run the following OpenSSL command I get an error...

```
openssl s_client -debug -connect example.com:443

Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

And if I check the domain on Digicert I get...

```
SSL Certificate is not trusted
```

I use the same type of setup for other projects (SSL on LB) and it works fine. Its only my Nginx instance that is giving me trouble.
Is there some configuration I could be missing with Nginx?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing some intermediate certificates perhaps?

Comment: Hi, this is where my knowledge of SSL starts to get a bit blurry. I'm aware of intermediate certificates but where should they go? On the LB or is this something specific to nginx? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate authority provides you with a signed certificate and (zero or more) intermediate certificates. You will need to check with whoever signed your certificate as to which (if any) intermediate certificates need to be bundled with your signed certificate.

In the `nginx` configuration file, the `ssl_certificate` directive specifies the file containing your signed certificate and any intermediate certificates concatenated together, with the signed certificate appearing first. This is a text file and should contain one or more sections between line markers:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.

Comment: So do I also need to install the certificates on nginx as well as the load balancer? Currently I just have the certificate installed on the Load Balancer

Comment: Sorry, no, the certificates only need to be installed at whichever process terminates the SSL connection. If the load balancer proxies to `nginx` using HTTP only, then `nginx` does not need the certificates. Apologies for the references to `nginx`.

Comment: No problem! So I should be installing intermediate certificates on the Load Balancer then?

Comment: If your certificate requires intermediate certificates, then they must be installed with it.

Comment: That worked! I merged the certificates together into a single file. There is also a bug with the AWS UI whereby the intermediate certificate field seems to not work. Instead I have the single file with all the certificates in the one field